# How to fix the error Angular 15 "401 ERROR Unauthorized"

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

Please help me fix the error. The component is not loaded.

Thank you.

- [Screen first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEnA.png)
- [Screen second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1ciS.png)

**error.interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) && this.accountService.accountValue) {
                this.accountService.logout();
            }

            const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText;
            console.error(err);
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are unauthorized. What are you having problems with? Should you be authorized?

Comment: Hi. The login page should show up, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for responding, problem solved. I updated rxjs and it worked.